# strnicmp equivalent for UTF-8?

Tags: c++, utf-8, case-insensitive, string-comparison

What do I use to perform a case-insensitive comparison on two UTF-8 encoded sub-strings?  Essentially, I'm looking for a `strnicmp` function for UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case conversion rules in various Unicode scripts are murderously difficult, it requires large case conversion tables.  You cannot get this right yourself, you'll need a library.  ICU is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`strcoll` should be locale aware and treat correctly UTF8 at least if it is the default encoding of the locale. If it is not, I have still no idea. Like a workaround, you can convert the multibyte string into wchars (mbrtowc) and then use wcscasecmp which unfortunately is a GNU extension, not a part of standard libraries... Not so useful maybe.

Comment: Is strcoll case-insensitive?  Is there a way to specify the maximum number of characters to compare?